# An efficient way to display a lot of items in Android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I would like to know what is the best and most efficient way for both the user and developer(me) to display more than 100 items.  Right now I have them all in a ExpandableListView.  Every group carry's 11 child items(there are 10 groups).  This is not being pulled from any database and is all static information(images textview's).  I'm trying to design this so the user can get to information quickly. If anyone knows a better way to do this, please share.

Comment: Will need more info to answer.  Are you pulling data from a database? Are you rendering images? Are you pulling anything down from the net? How often are you mutating the adapter or will it be static data?  Do you need to filter the data on the fly?

Comment: I'm using static data(textview's, images) with each child.

Comment: Are images about icon sized found in the Drawable folder...or large graphics from Drawables folder?  Or are the images bitmaps that you'll be loading from disk manually?

Comment: All of the images are being loaded from the drawable-xhdpi folder. So I guess you could say they are about icon sized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it sounds like you have a pretty simple set of data you wish to show the user. And seeing that you need to show 100 or such items, there's not many options when it comes to efficiency for both user and you.

`ExpandableListView` is def a good choice.  It'll allow the user to select which portion of the data to view at a time. It's not hard to get one rolling either.  Android provides a very basic [SimpleExpandableListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleExpandableListAdapter.html) which is good for displaying static data. The most difficult part in working with it is assembling your data into the format it requires.

Another alternative is some sort of Tabbed display. Selecting each tab would load a new `ListView` of data.  Basically the tabs here would be equivalent to the groups in the `ExpandableListView`. This could allow for showing more items within each grouping because the tabs would only span one row across the screen horizontally.  You could implement different ways but here's a [link](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html) which introduces and walks you through one. From the user perspective, this approach is merely a change in look and feel really...it's a bit more involved for the programmer to implement.

Comment: I think I'll stick to the ExpandableListView, since it seems like a sensible option for both the user and me.